# How can I access messages in discussions of posts on channels through the Telegram API?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I've read the documentation and couldn't find the answer, has anyone encountered this problem before?

I am using the Telethon library for Python.
I only need to retrieve the text of messages from discussions in channels where my bot is a member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function to retrieve all comments text from one post:

```
def get_comments(client: TelegramClient, channel: str, post_id: int):
    async def crawl_comments():
        async for message in client.iter_messages(channel, reply_to=post_id, reverse=True):
            comment = message.text
            print(comment)
    with client:
       client.loop.run_until_complete(crawl_comments())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all messages by following the below steps:

- initialize a telethon client
- fetch messages from a channel

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = 'YOUR_API_ID'  # Replace with your API ID
api_hash = 'YOUR_API_HASH'  # Replace with your API hash
phone_number = 'YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER'  # Replace with your phone number (used for the login)

# Initialize the Telethon client
with TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    
    # Ensure you are signed in (if not, this will ask for the code Telegram sends you)
    client.start()

    # Replace 'SomeChannel' with the username of the channel
    # If the channel doesn't have a username, you'll need its ID
    for message in client.iter_messages('SomeChannel'):
        print(message.text)
```

Comment: I just need comments from discussions under posts in channels